# Posting data using ajax in an MVC controller not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem posting my data to a controller using ajax, I am trying to send a string to a controller via ajax but it doesn't even reach the controller, my code is like this:

```
var m_page_nm = $('#pagemenu_hid').val(),
oColumns = JSON.stringify(this.oKgrid.columns),
data = JSON.stringify({ columns: oColumns, page_name: m_page_nm, grid_nm:     this.m_kgrid_id });

$.ajax({
    url: "/Favorite/SaveColumnSettings",
    type: 'POST',             
    data:{ gridset:data },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    },               
});
```

and in the controller its just as simple as this

**[HttpPost]**

```
public ActionResult SaveColumnSettings(string gridset)
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

on the developer tools was this request

```
Request URL:http://localhost:2144/Favorite/SaveColumnSettings
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:2144
Referer:http://localhost:2144/Agent/Index?menu=AGENT_SETUP
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)             Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
gridset:{"columns":" [{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Id\",\"hidden\":true,\"field\":\"agent_no\",\"filterable\":{},\"attributes\":{\"style\":\"display:none\"},\"footerAttributes\":{\"style\":\"display:none\"},\"headerAttributes\":{\"style\":\"display:none\"}},{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Agent Code\",\"width\":\"20px\",\"field\":\"agent_cd\",\"groupable\":false,\"filterable\":{}},{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Agent Name\",\"width\":\"80px\",\"field\":\"agent_nm\",\"groupable\":false,\"filterable\":{}},{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Supervisory Code\",\"width\":\"20px\",\"field\":\"supervisor_cd\",\"filterable\":{}},{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Sales Dept. Code\",\"width\":\"20px\",\"field\":\"sdept_cd\",\"filterable\":{}},{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Area\",\"width\":\"20px\",\"field\":\"area_cd\",\"filterable\":{}},{\"encoded\":true,\"title\":\"Active?\",\"width\":\"10px\",\"template\":\"<div style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' disabled checked #= inactive_yn? checked='checked': checked='' # class='chkbx' /></div>\",\"field\":\"inactive_yn\",\"filterable\":{}}]","page_name":"AGENT_SETUP","grid_nm":"#agent_kgrid"}
```

Comment: any error? Or use google chrome developer tools(f12) or firefox firebugs to check whether the url is correct

Comment: i dont have any error on the developer tools. My problem is it don't reach my controller even if the url was right, when it reached the controller, the parameter is null... im stocked with this for days

Comment: @Se0ng11 i have the edit above... I have that request sent but it doesn't reach my controller

Comment: I see that your json is not valid, try use tools like http://jsoneditoronline.org/index.html to check whether your json is correct, thats all I can help

Comment: @Se0ng11 the site says i have 3 objects, that means my json was right..??? the columns was a string, then page_nm and grid_nm

Comment: then try to change your parameter, just for testing purpose to, public ActionResult SaveColumnSettings(string columns, string page_nm, string grid_nm) and see whether it get the value

Comment: Your controller action accepts only one parameter but you've multiple parameters encoded in json but none of them matches with the name as gridset. Try changing the name of parameter from gridset to `grid_nm`

Comment: im a newbie in ajax, just a week ago i am still learning now.. it takes me a lot of time to solve this

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code I found these -

1. You are not using `ajax` success callback method, so even if you are getting correct result you won't be able to know. Add `success` method, a sample would be like (Use a JS console to view the result , may be FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools) -

   `$.ajax({
       url: "/Favorite/SaveColumnSettings",
       type: 'POST',

       data:{ gridset:data },
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       error: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       },

       success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
   });`
2. You are using `dataType:json` in the code, so the result will be automatically parsed to json object. So you won't get a normal xhr response therefore `xhr.statusText` is invalid. The result is already `json` and since you returned `EmptyResult` the result is empty, thus `data` should be blank or null.
3. You are using `EmptyResult`, using `dataType:json` - This options is not connected to server, this is to let jQuery know that your response is `json` and so jQuery will automatically parse it when calling `error` or `success` callback. So with `EmptyResult` its insignificant
4. To make it work change the return `EmptyResult` to something like this (This is the syntax I use, there are others too, I don't have VS installed right now, so the syntax might be a bit wrong, but you can always find easily. )-

   `return MVCHelperUtilites.GetJsonResult(new []{
       new KeyValuePair<String,String>("Success",True)
   });`
5. If you are still willing to use `EmptyResult` use `dataType:html` instead

Comment: gonna try this @Mahmud

Comment: Use firebug or chrome dev tools to see the response of the ajax call.

Comment: Thats a server side error. Debug it with VS, by the way remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` it won't help that much, controller will detect json by themselves, I never use them

Comment: Im already 2 days debugging this problem.. It doesnt reach the controller, or when it reaches the controller it has a null value

Comment: 500 means.. server error, if it reaches it will be null cause you are returning empty...

Comment: I think I found it mahmud. I violated a rule on MVC.. I found the Error. Gonna get back to you when this works

Comment: got it @Mahmud!! I use for loop in the columns to save just the needed attributes and in the internal error problems, it was about cross site scripting error.. I got my codes working properly now